# receiving props from App.js using componentWillRecieveProps

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, redux

- In my app.js for the button component I gave this props `propTwo={"two"}`
- but still Button.js nothing is printing inside componentWillReceiveProps
- can yoi tell me how to recieve the props using componentWillReceiveProps method
- can you tell me how to use componentWillReceiveProps in my application
- providing my code snippet and sandbox below

https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-villani-xyikq

```
class Button extends Component {
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextprops) {
    console.log("componentWillReceiveProps nextprops--->", nextprops);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            // getPosts(channel);
            //  getAlert();
          }}
          className="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"
        >
          Get top news
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**App.js**

```
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <RecentChannelItem />
    <ChannelsField propOne={"one"} />
    <Button propTwo={"two"} />
    <TopNews />
  </div>
);
```

Comment: From [the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops), emphasis mine: "React *doesn’t call* UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps() *with initial props during mounting*. It only calls this method if some of component’s props may update." Also, as at least one answer points out, this method is deprecated and will be completely gone in the next version of React, so learning it isn't doing yourself any favors.

Comment: can you tell me how to achieve with componentWill Receive props

Comment: No. It's a *deprecated* method. Note the UNSAFE at the beginning in all caps. As in "we're getting rid of this thing because it's error-prone and causes problems, so don't use it. Ever."

Comment: @JaredSmith I have codebase which uses componentWillRecieveProps, so I am trying to learn with an example, can you update my sandbox :(

Comment: You will have to change your codebase unless you plan to never ever touch it ever again. And the fact that you're asking here means that you are in fact actively developing it. You're going to have to go through and change that throughout your codebase, and I'm sorry because I've been there and I know that sucks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

componentWillReceiveProps is already deprecated.

You can use [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate).

You can access the updated props by accessing this.props inside the componentDidUpdate.

Comment: can you tell me how to achieve with componentWill Receive props

Comment: I have codebase which uses componentWillRecieveProps, so I am trying to learn with an example, can you update my sandbox :(

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextprops) {
    console.log("componentWillReceiveProps nextprops--->", nextprops);
  }
```

Comment: can you tell me how to achieve with componentWill Receive props

Comment: I have codebase which uses componentWillRecieveProps, so I am trying to learn with an example, can you update my sandbox :(